# ¿cómo actualizar registro en SQLite Android?

Tags: android, sql

Buenas, ojalá puedan ayudarme que no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, tengo mi actividad que inserta registros según se seleccione de la lista, pero antes de entrar al try-catch, necesito actualizar el registro anterior en el campo tiempo_transcurrido=System.currentTimeMillis(); para que cada vez que pase me valla registrando la duración del registro anterior en base del nuevo.

tengo mi actividad

`

```
public class Lista extends Activity {

    public static android.widget.ListView list;

    //valores a  insert
    long identificador=0L;
    String codigo_ac="";
    Long tiempo_inicio=0L;
    Long tiempo_termino=0L;
    Long tiempo_transcurrido=0L;
    int cantidad_tipo_actividad = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        cantidad_tipo_actividad = datos.getInt("cantidad_tipo_actividad");

        list = (android.widget.ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_id);


        final SQLiteHelper MDB = new SQLiteHelper(Lista.this);
        String[] sp1;
        int val = 0;
        try {
            try {
                val = MDB.validacionActividadCodigoEquipo(cantidad_tipo_actividad, ce, 1).size();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                val = 0;
            }
            if (val > 0) {
                sp1 = new String[MDB.validacionActividadCodigoEquipo(cantidad_tipo_actividad, ce, 1).size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < MDB.validacionActividadCodigoEquipo(cantidad_tipo_actividad, ce, 1).size(); i++) {
                    sp1[i] = MDB.validacionActividadCodigoEquipo(cantidad_tipo_actividad, ce, 1).get(i).getNombre_actividad();
                }
            } else {
                sp1 = new String[MDB.getAllActividadxTipoActividad(cantidad_tipo_actividad, 1).size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < MDB.getAllActividadxTipoActividad(cantidad_tipo_actividad, 1).size(); i++) {
                    sp1[i] = MDB.getAllActividadxTipoActividad(cantidad_tipo_actividad, 1).get(i).getNombre_actividad();
                }
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sp1);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setClickable(true);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    Uri notificacion = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notificacion);
                    r.play();

                    final SQLiteHelper MDB = new SQLiteHelper(Lista.this);
                    try {
                        //input actuales
                        identificador=INICIO;
                        codigo_ac=actividad"
                        tiempo_inicio=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        tiempo_termino=0L;
                        long tiempo_transcurrido_;
                        String ca=MDB.obtenerCodigoAC();
                        if (ca.equals("INICIO")){
                            tiempo_transcurrido_= 0;
                        } else {
                            tiempo_transcurrido_=tiempo_inicio-Long.parseLong(MDB.obtenerTiempoInicioAnterior());
                        }
                        tiempo_transcurrido=tiempo_transcurrido_;

                        MDB.insertar_registros(identificador,codigo_ac,tiempo_inicio,tiempo_termino,tiempo_transcurrido);

                        //limpiar parametros setting
                        identificador=0L;
                        codigo_ac="";
                        tiempo_inicio=0L;
                        tiempo_termino=0L;
                        tiempo_transcurrido=0;

                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(Lista.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            sp1 = new String[]{"SIN REGISTROS"};

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sp1);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

y este es el SQLHelper

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 1;

    // Nombre de nuestro archivo de base de datos
    private static final String NOMBRE_BASEDATOS = "proeq.db";

    // Nombre tabla
    private static final String NOMBRE_TABLA="registros";
    private static final String NOMBRE_TABLA2="actividad";  


    // Sentencia SQL para la creación de una tabla
    private static final String SQL_DATOS = "CREATE TABLE " + NOMBRE_TABLA + "(codigo_registro INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, identificador long, codigo_ac text, tiempo_inicio long, tiempo_termino long, tiempo_transcurrido";
    private static final String SQL_DATOS2 = "CREATE TABLE " + NOMBRE_TABLA3 + "(codigo_actividad int, nombre_actividad text, tipo_actividad int, tipos_horas_proeq int, codigo_equipos text, estado int)";

    // CONSTRUCTOR de la clase
    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DATOS);
        db.execSQL(SQL_DATOS2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOMBRE_TABLA);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOMBRE_TABLA2);
        onCreate(db);
    }

     public void insertar_actividad(int codigo_actividad,String nombre_actividad,int tipo_actividad, int tipos_horas_proeq, String codigo_equipos, int estado) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("codigo_actividad", codigo_actividad);
            valores.put("nombre_actividad", nombre_actividad);
            valores.put("tipo_actividad", tipo_actividad);
            valores.put("tipos_horas_proeq", tipos_horas_proeq);
            valores.put("codigo_equipos", codigo_equipos);
            valores.put("estado",estado);
            db.insert("actividad", null, valores);
            //db.insertOrThrow("datos",null,valores);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public void insertar_registros_proeq( long identificador,String codigo_ac, long tiempo_inicio, long tiempo_termino, long tiempo_transcurrido) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("identificador", identificador);
            valores.put("codigo_ac", codigo_ac);
            valores.put("tiempo_inicio", tiempo_inicio);
            valores.put("tiempo_termino", tiempo_termino);
            valores.put("tiempo_transcurrido", tiempo_transcurrido);
            //db.insertOrThrow("datos",null,valores);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public void limpiar_bd_registros_proeq() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("registros_proeq", null, null);
        db.close();
    }
    public void limpiar_bd_actividad() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("actividad", null, null);
        db.close();
    }
    public List<ObjetoActividad> validacionActividadCodigoEquipo(int n,String ce,int es) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        List<ObjetoActividad> lista_datos = new ArrayList<ObjetoActividad>();
        String[] valores_recuperar = {"codigo_actividad", "nombre_actividad", "tipo_actividad", "tipos_horas_proeq", "codigo_equipos", "estado"};
        Cursor c = db.query("actividad", valores_recuperar,"tipo_actividad="+n+" and codigo_equipos='"+ce+"' and estado='"+es+"'",null,null,null,null,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            ObjetoActividad datos = new ObjetoActividad(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getInt(2), c.getInt(3), c.getString(4), c.getInt(5));
            lista_datos.add(datos);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return lista_datos;
    }    
   public String obtenerCodigoAC() {
        String cr = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "select MAX(codigo_registro) as codigo_registro,codigo_ac from registros";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            cr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("codigo_ac"));
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return cr;
    }
   public String obtenerTiempoInicioAnterior() {
        String cr = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "select MAX(codigo_registro) as codigo_registro,tiempo_inicio from registros where codigo_ac!='INICIO' ";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            cr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("tiempo_inicio"));
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return cr;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso tienes el método update()

```
ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
valores.put("campo_a_actualizar","valor_a_actualizar");
db.update("tabla_a_actualizar", valores, "claúsula WHERE", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Llamamos al helper

```
 SQLiteHelper MDB = new SQLiteHelper(Activity.this);
 Boolean estado_insert=MDB.actualizarEstadoEnvio(1,idt2);
```

Y el helper se modifica así

```
   public boolean actualizarEstadoEnvio(int estado,String idt) {

        int filasAfectadas = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if(db!=null){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("enviado", estado);
            filasAfectadas= db.update("registros",values,"idt="+idt,null);
        }
        return filasAfectadas > 0;
    }
```